# Watchify Excluded File Compiling Issue

Tags: npm, browserify, watchify

I am having trouble with Watchify when trying to exclude a file ([like so in Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles)).

Using this command:

```
watchify scripts/main.js -o scripts/main.bundle.js -t strictify -v -x scripts/libs.js
```

It compiles fine at first, but then gives an error when making any updates to watched files. This is the full output:

```
1036 bytes written to scripts/main.bundle.js (0.04 seconds)

fs.js:430
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:430:11)
    at OpenReq.process (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:55:16)
    at OpenReq.Req (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:126:8)
    at new OpenReq (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:49:7)
    at Object.open (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:41:3)
    at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1509:6)
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1496:10)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1450:10)
    at Deps.readFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:190:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:365:14
```

Is this a known issue with any workarounds? For now, I can redact the `-x scripts/libs.js` and do a regular Browserify build for production (to exclude the file), but for development this makes for a slightly slower Watchify task.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your version of watchify?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround was skipping Watchify altogether and using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to handle the watching. This is the full package.json used for development and production builds:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "node-sass": "latest",
        "autoprefixer": "latest",
        "browserify": "latest",
        "strictify": "latest",
        "uglify-js": "latest",
        "nodemon": "latest"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build:main:bundle": "browserify scripts/main.js -o scripts/main.bundle.js -x ./scripts/libs.js -t strictify",
        "build:main:uglify": "uglifyjs scripts/main.bundle.js -c -o scripts/main.bundle.js",
        "build:main": "npm run build:main:bundle && npm run build:main:uglify",
        "build:libs:bundle": "browserify -r ./scripts/libs.js -o scripts/libs.bundle.js -t strictify",
        "build:libs:uglify": "uglifyjs scripts/libs.bundle.js -c -o scripts/libs.bundle.js",
        "build:libs": "npm run build:libs:bundle && npm run build:libs:uglify",
        "build:styles": "node-sass --stdout --output-style compressed styles/styles.scss | autoprefixer -o styles/styles.css",
        "build": "npm run build:main && npm run build:libs && npm run build:styles",
        "watch:main": "nodemon -e js -w scripts -i scripts/main.bundle.js -x 'npm run build:main:bundle'",
        "watch:styles": "nodemon -e scss -w styles -x 'npm run build:styles'",
        "watch": "npm run watch:main & npm run watch:styles"
    }
}
```

This allows using these two commands for development (using watch) and production (using build):

```
npm run watch
npm run build
```

The only caveat would be to do a manual

```
npm run build:libs
```

for whenever updating the scripts/libs.js file (which has files like jQuery/Backbone/TweenLite in it, so you shouldn't have to update often). For a full example, see this: [Weblate](https://bitbucket.org/davidsinclair/weblate).

Thanks to [NPM for Everything](http://beletsky.net/2015/04/npm-for-everything.html) for helping find a solution...even if it does not solve the Watchify issue directly...